# Why H/Cs/I atomic clocks are more complicated than Rb?

Tags: atomic-physics, atomic-clocks

It is known that low-cost commercial Rb atomic clocks are fairly simple in construction: gas cell is probed by a light source and excited by RF around 6.8Ghz. When frequency is right - we see decrease of the photodiode signal.

But if we look at Cs and H clocks - they are not using this principle, but instead have fountains/masers, complicated mechanisms for selection of right states... Why Cs/H clocks can't use same simple design with RF excitation of gas cell and probing with light source?

Same for Iodine - it has huge number of lines in visible and NIR spectrum which are easy to probe at low cost. Aren't there any that can react to RF excitation <12Ghz and can be used as a time source?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191871/123208 has some info on the benefits of caesium over rubidium. Also see [HP 5062C Cesium Beam Frequency Reference](http://www.leapsecond.com/museum/hp5062c/theory.htm).

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, this is more or less clear. But design of Cs clock is much more complicated, it does not use optical probe. That is the question - I really like simplicity of Rb clock, and trying to understand why Cs/H clock need to be complicated, and Iodine clocks are done in optical domain only, where it is even more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Rubidium Frequency Standard Primer](http://www.wriley.com/Rubidium%20Frequency%20Standard%20Primer%20102211.pdf),

> Before the availability of spectroscopic lasers, rubidium was the atom
> of choice for gas cell devices because of its unique ability to use
> isotopic hyperfine filtering of the pumping light from a Rb lamp.
>
> The efficiency of the optical pumping process is enhanced by a
> fortuitous overlap between the optical absorption lines of the two
> naturally-occurring isotopes, 85Rb and 87Rb. This is the main reason
> that rubidium is used in most (non-laser pumped) gas cell atomic
> frequency standards. Rubidium is unique in that the 85Rb isotope can
> serve as a hyperfine filter to remove one of the hyperfine components
> from the light emitted by an 87Rb spectral lamp as shown in Figure 6.
>
> In this cartoon figure (see Figure 7 for real spectra), the top plot
> shows the two hyperfine components in the optical spectrum of one of
> the 87Rb D-lines. Because both hyperfine components are present at
> equal intensities, this light would be ineffective for the purpose of
> optical pumping. The middle plot shows the absorption spectrum of 85Rb
> gas. Notice that the “a” and “A” components overlap while the “b” and
> “B” components do not. If the 87Rb lamp spectrum is passed through the
> 85Rb filter cell, the resulting filtered spectrum is shown in the
> bottom plot. The desired “b” component is now significantly larger
> than the “a” component, making the filtered spectrum more effective as
> an optical pumping source for an 87Rb absorption cell. The filter cell
> can be separate or integrated with the absorption (resonance) cell by
> using natural Rb with both isotopes.